# Count function and Case

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hue

Counting number of opportunities where stage 1-8 should be counted as SAL, but then I want to filter only Stage 3-7 as SQL.

Tried case statement and counting in a sub query which didn't work. Code below:

```
SELECT camp, count(opp_id) as sal, 
count(opp_id (select opp_id from db.opp_data_q3 where stage not in ("01", "02")) as sql,
 from db.opp_data_q3 
where created_quarter = "Q3" 
group by camp;
```

Expected Result:

```
Camp A | SAL 10 | SQL 5
Camp B | SAL 20 | SQL 3
```

Actual Result is an Error message:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:14 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'opp_id' 'from' in function specification

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select camp, count(*) as sal, 
       sum(case when stage not in ('01', '02') then 1 else 0 end) as sql
from db.opp_data_q3 
where created_quarter = 'Q3'
group by camp;
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me, still returns error:  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: line 3:32 Invalid function 'opp_id'

Comment: Nothing in the query is called `opp_id` so that is a very curious error.

Comment: No, in my new query I used the first suggestion as below and the error was the above >> 

SELECT camp, count(opp_id) as sal, 
count(opp_id (case when stage not in ("01", "02") then 1 else 0 end)) as sql 
 from db.opp_data_q3 
where created_quarter = "Q3" 
group by camp;

Comment: opp_id is the in the table >> db.opp_data_q3, which I want to count (not sum) since it is like order IDs, and each of them has a stage